# MacOs - Keep SMB server mounts alive on temporary VPN connection drops/reconnects

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, mount, samba

I am using SSTP VPN Connections (via SSTPc) on my MacBook and am mounting manually SMB Drives from the VPN Network.

Hwr, anytime my VPN Connection drops, my Mounts are unmounted and not there in Finder anymore. I then have to manually remount them.

Is there a way to keep those Mounts mounted or automatically remount when VPN connection is established again (not just on System Login)?

Comment: Is my Question bad?